# How to know if a string includes at least one element of array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

```
let theString = 'include all the information someone would need to answer your question'

let theString2 = 'include some the information someone would need to answer your question'

let theString3 = 'the information someone would need to answer your question'

let theArray = ['all', 'some', 'x', 'y', 'etc' ]
```

> theString true because there is 'all',
>       theString2 true because there is 'some',
>       theString3 false because there is no 'all' or 'some'

Comment: But there *is* `some` in `theString3` -- why would it return `false`?

Comment: Is there more detail you can provide on how you've defined 'includes'? As the above comment mentioned, there is techinically 'some' in 'someone'

Answer (score 2):

```
const theStringIsGood = theString.split(' ').some(word => theArray.includes(word))
```

This code splits a sentence into each word and check if any word matches the matching set, theArray.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the string.includes() method. But in this case theString3 would still return true because some is in something. You could create a helper function to see if a string is within an array instead:

```
function findString(arr, str) {
    let flag = false;
    let strArr = str.split(' ');
    arr.forEach(function(s) {
        strArr.forEach(function(s2) {
            if(s === s2) {
                flag = true;
            }
        });
    });
    return flag;
};
```

Now you can pass the array and one of the strings to the function and test it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with regex simply :

```
function ArrayInText(str, words) {
    let regex = new RegExp("\\b(" + words.join('|') + ")\\b", "g");
    return regex.test(str);
}
```

> in regex \b is words boundary

and notice, if you split all string yourself and check one by one, a lot of memory use, because it is a greedy solution. I offer that using javascript native functions.

snippet :

```js
let theString = 'include all the information someone would need to answer your question'

let theString2 = 'include some the information someone would need to answer your question'

let theString3 = 'the information someone would need to answer your question'

let theArray = ['all', 'some', 'x', 'y', 'etc']

function ArrayInText(str, words) {
    let regex = new RegExp("\\b(" + words.join('|') + ")\\b", "g");
    return regex.test(str);
}

console.log(ArrayInText(theString, theArray));
console.log(ArrayInText(theString2, theArray));
console.log(ArrayInText(theString3, theArray));
```

good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

1) `isIncludeWord` -- look for exact word match using `split` and `includes` method.

2) `isInclude` -- look for match contain using `some` and `includes`.

```js
let theString =
  "include all the information someone would need to answer your question";
let theString2 =
  "include some the information someone would need to answer your question";
let theString3 = "the information someone would need to answer your question";
let theArray = ["all", "some", "x", "y", "etc"];

const isIncludeWord = (str, arr) =>
  str.split(" ").reduce((include, word) => include || arr.includes(word), false);

const isInclude = (str, arr) => arr.some(item => str.includes(item));

console.log(isIncludeWord(theString, theArray));
console.log(isIncludeWord(theString2, theArray));
console.log(isIncludeWord(theString3, theArray));

console.log(isInclude(theString, theArray));
console.log(isInclude(theString2, theArray));
console.log(isInclude(theString3, theArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the question is 100% correct,
but here's a way to check if a string contains at least one element of a strings-array

Using the [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method:

```
words.find((word) => str.includes(word))
```